# how to get values from xml file then print them using php

Tags: php, xml

i have xml file with the following format

```
<mainvalue>
<asd><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>yes</active></asd>
<qwe><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>no</active></qwe>
<zxc><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>yes</active></zxc>
</mainvalue>
```

i need to get the values of `<asd>, <qwe> and <zxc>` since i only know how to get values as name or anything solid but not random values. plus getting the `active` status
and then export these values to `php` page with style such as `<span class="<?php echo $active_status; ?>"><?php echo $value;</span>`

please note that i do need the values as separate names and not all together.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to the rescue!

This is pretty straightforward example code. I've left the final string output formatting as an exercise to the reader.

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<mainvalue>
<asd><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>yes</active></asd>
<qwe><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>no</active></qwe>
<zxc><url>http://someurl.com</url><active>yes</active></zxc>
</mainvalue>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node instanceof DOMElement) {
        echo $node->nodeName . "\t"; // wacky node name
        echo $xpath->evaluate('string(./active)', $node) . "\n"; // serious active value
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
asd yes
qwe no
zxc yes
```

Comment: thanks a lot, will give it a try and i think it will work, but cant i also simplexml_load_file instead of adding all the values of the xml file manually, since i need it to be auto updated from the xml file.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($xml_name)
```

to load xml file; then

```
echo $sxe->asd->url->attributes();
```

to access it